# Restoring Postgresql database on Windows if only "data" folder available?

Tags: postgresql

Is is possible to restore a PostgreSQL database if all I have available is the "data" (C:\PostgreSQL\data in my case) folder of the server whose databases I want to restore.I know this folder contains all the database files but I have no idea how to go about restoring the databases in this scenario. I'm using PostgreSQL 10 and Win 2008 R2.

Comment: So Postgres is already installed? Was that data folder created with the same (major) Postgres version?

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes it was

Comment: @eckes  try what?

Comment: Restore the folder and see what happens. If it is the same version it should work. Stop the database, delete the data folder, restore the backup, start the database.